# find special keys in UserDefaults by "substringToIndex"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm grouping my UserDefault keys by specific prefixes.

e.g.

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: 1 forKey: @"prefix1_someText_Key"]
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: 2 forKey: @"prefix2_someText_Key"]
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: 3 forKey: @"prefix4_someText_Key"]
//.....
```

Now, I'd like to find all the keys, that start with e.g. "prefix", and load them into an array. is there a way for doing that (programmatically)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the underlying NSDictionary to find the suitable keys:

```
NSString *myPrefix = @"prefix";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dict = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
NSMutableArray *keysWithPrefix = [NSMutableArray array]
for (NSString *key in dict.keyEnumerator) {
  if ([key hasPrefix: myPrefix]) {
    [keysWithPrefix addObject: key];
  }
}
// now keysWithPrefix contains all matching keys
```

**UPDATE**
For debugging reasons you could add a log to see what keys are being dropped:

```
for (NSString *key in dict.keyEnumerator) {
  if ([key hasPrefix: myPrefix]) {
    [keysWithPrefix addObject: key];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Dropping key %@", key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer but why did you add the ...?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I've been searching so long for something like this!

Comment: @Joe just to indicate that there could be any prefix.

Comment: @smudo78 maybe a long shot, but is there at least one key in your UserDefaults, that does not start with your prefix? Added a debugging help to the code. Maybe that will show you where the bug occurs.

Comment: Shouldn't `[re addObject: key];` be `[keysWithPrefix addObject: key];` ? (or am I missing something?). Also the array assignment line is missing a semicolon.

Comment: @Alladinian d'oh, you're right. When I first wrote that code I named the NSArray `re` but decided to rename it for readability. Updated that.